# Why does Tridion report Chrome 100+ as "unsupported browser"?

Tags: cme, sites-9, sites-9.1, sites-9.5

Since the release of Chrome 100, Tridion is showing the error "SDL Tridion Sites has not been tested, and is not guaranteed to work, with the browser you are using".

[image]

Why is that?

I think this happens on every version since SDL Web 8.

Comment: I find it rather embarrassing that the error screen is showing html code. It's the same on our client's 9.5 servers.

Comment: Embarrassing from the standpoint that this error handling was apparently never tested (if it had been tested, people would probably also have realized that the version number might get more than 2 digits at some time).  However, from a security standpoint, one could defend that at least this dialog does not allow HTML injection. ;-)

Comment: Does anyone realize that all Tridion users who are on 9.5 or 9.6 and use Chrome, Edge or (soon) Firefox can no longer use the CMS at all? When will this be hotfixed? What's taking you guys so long?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tridion uses regular expressions to validate browser versions. The regex for Chrome does not work with versions above 100. You can change this yourself. Just open the file %TRIDION_HOME%\Web\WebUI\WebRoot\Configuration\System.config, look for the line containing '<browser name="Google Chrome 50+"' and change it to:

```
<browser name="Google Chrome 50+" regExp="Chrome/([5-9]\d+|\d\d\d+)"/>
```

While you're at it, also change the line for Firefox (because FF is also approaching the 100 fast):

```
<browser name="Mozilla Firefox 47+" regExp="Firefox/(4[7-9]|[5-9]\d+|\d\d\d+)" />
```